# URL Reverse with Django/Django.js and WSGIScriptAlias

Tags: javascript, django, url

I've got a problem with my django project in my production environement. When I use an alias for the "WSGIScriptAlias" apache directive, it looks like I've got a problem with the reverse URL. In fact the problem is probably related to the [django.js](http://djangojs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module as it doesn't seems to take into account the "WSGIScriptAlias".

So, here is my apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /MyPath/django_proj/pti/pti
    WSGIScriptAlias /pti /MyPath/django_proj/pti/pti/pti_project/wsgi.py

    WSGIDaemonProcess pti python-path=/MyPath/django_proj/pti/pti:/MyPath/django_proj/pti/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup pti

    Alias /media/ /MyPath/django_proj/pti/pti/media_root/
    Alias /static/ /MyPath/django_proj/pti/pti/static_root/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/pti-error_log
    <Directory /MyPath/django_proj/pti/pti/pti_project/>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Allow from all  
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /MyPath/django_proj/pti/pti/static_root/>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /MyPath/django_proj/pti/pti/media_root/>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

As you can see my WSGIScriptAlias is "/pti".

My django URLs is :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'pti_project.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^djangojs/', include('djangojs.urls')),
url(r'^pti_core/', include('pti_core.urls', namespace='pti_core', app_name='pti_core')),
url(r'^pti_map/', include('pti_map.urls',  namespace='pti_map', app_name='pti_map')),
)
```

This part seems to work fine. But the problem comes when I use the [url's reverse django.js](http://djangojs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/djangojs.html#reverse-urls) fonction to get my data. here is my url's pti_map configuration file where my data are stored is :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('pti_map.views',
url(r'^$', 'map_index', name='map_index'),
url(r'^ptiretrait.geojson$', MapLayer.as_view(model=PtiRetrait), name='ptiretrait'),
url(r'^ptiencours.geojson$', MapLayer.as_view(model=PtiEnCours), name='ptiencours'),
url(r'^ptinouvelle.geojson$', GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=PtiNvlleDetection, precision = 5, simplify=0.5,  properties  = ('etat', 'friche', 'age', 'acces', 'culture', 'bati', 'voisinage', 'defrichement', 'mecanisable', 'irrigable', 'commentaire')), name='ptinouvelle'),
url(r'^newptisubmit$', 'newptisubmit', name='newptisubmit'),
url(r'^newptiedit$', 'newptiedit', name='newptiedit'),
url(r'^newptimodifygeom$', 'newptimodifygeom', name='newptimodifygeom'),
url(r'^ptiTable$', 'ptiTable', name='ptiTable'),
url(r'^sendEmail$', 'sendEmail', name='sendEmail'),
url(r'ajax_file_upload$', 'ajax_file_upload', name="ajax_file_upload"),
)
```

When I try to get my reverse URL using this function, it doesn't seems to take into accout my WSGIScriptAlias. So using the django.js reverse urls function, the result for 
`Django.url('pti_map:ptinouvelle')` is:

`http://MyServer/pti_map/ptinouvelle.geojson`

instead of the one I expected :

`http://MyServer/pti/pti_map/ptinouvelle.geojson`

I can confirm that "django.js" doesn't seems to take into account my WSGIScriptAlias. here is the result of my `console.log(Django.urls)`:

```
pti_map:ptiencours "/pti_map/ptiencours.geojson"

pti_map:ptinouvelle "/pti_map/ptinouvelle.geojson"

pti_map:ptiretrait "/pti_map/ptiretrait.geojson"
```

If I want to make it worked I have to hard code the WSGIScriptAlias in my JS file:

`var url = "/pti" + Django.url('pti_map:ptinouvelle')`

By adding "/pti" in the beginning of the URL I can get my data, but it's an ugly hack and it breaks my compatibility with my development platform.

Do you have any idea how I could solve this issue ?

Thanks.

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because your Django app doesn't know anything about the rewriting or the routing your web server is doing, it's outside it's scope.

You might have done the aliasing because you want to host something else as well on some other route. If this is the situation then what you can do is, you can internally route requests to /pti_map to /pti_map/pti_map and use the alias /pti_map to your script.

What this will do it while routing the request to the script, the wsgi container will eat up the first "pti_map" and will forward the next one.

Hope I understood you correctly.